# Check a DOM element type/attribute to assign a value to innerHTML or value

Tags: javascript

I want to  query over all in a selected container.

```
container = document.querySelector('[data-container]')
```

I also have a `variable` that contains a value.

If the child elements have a `value` attribute (like inputs)

```
child.value = variable
```

If not, like 'p', 'div' use:

```
child.innerHTML = variable
```

How do I check the element/type attribute?

Do I need to check tag by tag, or is something more general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something more general: `in`: It checks to see if a property exists on an object (or its prototypes):

```
if ("value" in element) {
    // use value
} else {
    // Use innerHTML or textContent, etc.
}
```

Example:

```js
var container = document.querySelector("[data-container]");
var children = container.children;
for (var n = 0; n < children.length; ++n) {
  var element = children[n];
  var hasValue = "value" in element;
  console.log(element.tagName, hasValue ? "has value" : "doesn't have value");
}
```

```html
<div data-container>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```